# Linking backend tables

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is is possible to link tables freshly from sql backend tables via ms access front-end using vba code?

The idea is to create links on successful logins and delete the links after log off. In this way the linked tables are not accessible offline via ms access front-ends and deleting the links does not delete the tables in the backend.

Comment: I'd keep it simple. No successful logon, no access.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to store your connection info

currentdb.createtabledef("nameoftabletocreate", ,"nameoftableinsource", "yourconnection")